# Internal server error with Flask trying to run python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have set up a basic Flask page, index.html to run my app.py script. Directory structure is myapp folder containing app.py, templates folder containing index.html, and a venv folder. I am trying to get my app.py script (which downloads an excel file, and it works when run by itself in ipython) to run upon clicking a GO button. I can get flask to run on localhost easy enough and index.html appears with the button, but when I click it I get - "Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

I've tried for ages and looked at other similar questions but to no avail.
Code for app.py is as follows:

```
            #!/usr/bin/env python

            from flask import Flask, render_template

            app = Flask(__name__)


            @app.route('/')
            def index():
                return render_template('index.html')


            @app.route('/app', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
                def app():

                import selenium
                from selenium import webdriver
                from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
                from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
                import lxml
                import time
                import datetime
                import pandas as pd
                from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
                options = Options()
                options.headless = True
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
                driver.get('https://widget.sentryd.com/widget/#/15490A29-95E3-4296-999E-28D0B35E0D12/AUD-USD/4')
                time.sleep(10)
                soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
                table1 = soup1.find_all('table')
                df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1[1]), header=0)
                df1[0].columns = ['Delta_put', 'Price_put', 'Strike', 'Price_call', 'Delta_call', 'Vol', 'Skew', 'Vega']
                df1[0].drop(0, inplace=True)
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter('options_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%d %b %y')), engine='xlsxwriter')
                df1[0].to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
                writer.save()

            return 'Downloading...'


            if __name__ == '__main__':
            app.run()
```

Code for index.html is

```
<form action="/app" method="POST">
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Check the console in which flask is running for the error message.

Comment: Do the indenting on the `app()` function really look like that? You also have a variable `app` and a function `app()`.

Comment: no to the indenting, I just use autopep8 and it seems to work okay

Comment: Are you sure that when you click the GO button, the server is already up and running? can you navigate to /app from the browser without clicking the GO button?

Comment: you're right, I can't now for some reason the code when I was copy pasting messed things up. the original error code I got though when it was working is:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/webdev/Desktop/app/app.py", line 13, in foo
    import selenium
ImportError: No module named selenium

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: `pip install selenium` I think

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should put the error output in the question instead of the comments. That would help other people to answer your question as not everyone goes through the comments.

Based on the error however, it looks like you did not install the required modules and packages to run your application.

You have imported them here:

```
@app.route('/app', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def app():
        import selenium
        from selenium import webdriver
        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
        from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
        import lxml
        import time
        import datetime
        import pandas as pd
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You should install those modules using your preferred installation method.
You can use `pip` to install those.

So go to your project's environment, open the console and install them.

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
pip install selenium
pip install pandas
pip install lxml
```

Comment: Can you please paste your error in markdown formatting here @CandiceSmith